# Using subquery to compare date on same table

Tags: sql, subquery

I need to take the earn bonus data which is after latest vip use bonus between 1/5 to 30/6

My table as follow:

```
VIPCODE TXDATETIME      ACTION  BONUS
1       2019/04/01 17:24    E   7507
1       2019/05/28 20:00    E   2920
1       2019/05/30 20:00    U   -19200
1       2019/06/01 17:45    E   11000
1       2019/06/15 17:45    U   -4200
1       2019/06/20 13:30    E   400
2       2019/05/02 19:12    E   2700
2       2019/05/02 19:12    U   -14400
2       2019/05/06 17:30    E   1463
2       2019/06/06 17:30    U   -4400
2       2019/07/20 12:38    E   2010
3       2019/05/18 13:58    E   2955
3       2019/06/17 19:20    E   -9000
3       2019/06/18 20:16    E   1000
3       2019/06/24 16:42    E   2000
```

Even tried join table or subquery return error: 
missing right parenthesis

I have use this sql:

```
SELECT * FROM VIPPoint v where v.txdatetime between to_date('2019-05-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date('2019-06-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
and v.txdatetime > (SELECT * FROM VIPPoint d where d.XF_ACTION='U' and d.xf_txdatetime < to_date('2019-06-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') and v.VIPCODE
=d.VIPCODE and rownum=1 order by d.xf_txdatetime desc)
```

My expext output is:

```
VIPCODE TXDATETIME      ACTION  BONUS
1       2019/06/20 13:30    E   400
3       2019/06/18 20:16    E   1000
3       2019/06/24 16:42    E   2000
```

How can take data correctly?

Comment: your `subquery` will fail, should be matching 1 field

Comment: Aren't these data `3 2019/05/18 13:58 E 2955` and `3 2019/06/17 19:20 E -9000` also considered in the output ?

Comment: you can make a fiddle to reciprocate your error, it also helps us to understand your prblm.

Comment: @singwong . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Finall, I fix the problem with few step: 1. clone data to temp table 2.select each vipcode with latest action='U' date. 3. Remove row which is  < step 2 date(each vip have each sql generate by excel(or program)). 4. sum with each vip. i think it's not best practice but i need to finish it in time:)  Anyway, Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. There is an issue in your inner sub query as you are passing `*` for comparison with `datetime`. You should mention one column name in your inner query for performing comparison with `in`.

```
SELECT * FROM VIPPoint v 
where v.txdatetime between to_date('2019-05-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') and to_date('2019-06-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
and v.txdatetime > (SELECT d.txdatetime FROM VIPPoint d       ---- here you should pass your datetime column name instead of *
                    where d.XF_ACTION='U' 
                          and d.xf_txdatetime < to_date('2019-06-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
                          and v.VIPCODE=d.VIPCODE 
                          and rownum=1 
                    order by d.xf_txdatetime desc)
```

Comment: Thank you for your explain, it also return missing right parenthesis, even i change all * to a fieldname

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
SELECT * FROM VIPPoint v WHERE CONVERT(DATE,v.TXDATETIME) BETWEEN 
CONVERT(DATE, '2019-05-01') AND CONVERT(DATE, '2019-06-30') AND v.ACTION = 'E' 
AND v.TXDATETIME > (SELECT MAX(TXDATETIME) FROM VIPPoint vp 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,vp.TXDATETIME) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, '2019-05-01') 
AND CONVERT(DATE, '2019-06-30') AND vp.ACTION = 'U'AND vp.VIPCODE = v.VIPCODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT v.*,
             MAX(CASE WHEN v.XF_ACTION = 'U' THEN v.txdatetime END) OVER (PARTITION BY VIPCODE) as max_u_date
      FROM VIPPoint v 
      WHERE v.txdatetime >= DATE '2019-05-01' AND
            v.txdatetime < DATE '2019-07-01'
     ) v
WHERE XF_ACTION = 'E' AND
      txdatetime > max_u_date;
```

Notes:

- The `DATE` keyword may not be necessary.  Most databases understand constants in YYYY-MM-DD format.
- Do not use `BETWEEN` with date/times -- time components can mess up the comparisons.  The `>=`/`<` works with both dates and datetimes.